# How would a pilot stabilize the aircraft after a dual engine failure?

Tags: aircraft-performance, commercial-aviation, flight-training, general-aviation

Since there would be no more thrust, they would have to exchange energy by losing altitude to keep forward speed. But what happens towards the end, when you have to reduce your V/S to something like -800/min, would a pilot for a commercial airline, flying a commercial jet, stabilize his aircraft with flaps? Or would they just drop in altitude quickly to have a high airspeed and then just let it run off by leveling out and dropping the landing gear?

Comment: what do you mean by "stabilize"? don't airplanes usually stabilize themselves?

Comment: How many engines does your airplane have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than put up with one us speculating and pontificating on what to do, just read this terrific account of the Air Canada [Gimli Glider](https://www.damninteresting.com/the-gimli-glider/) incident, where a '67 did exactly that. They pretty much did it right, helped by a Capt that really knew how to ***fly*** as opposed to just being competent at running the machinery.

Comment: There are a number of other examples of airplanes losing all engines, yet landing safely (or managing a restart).  Wikipedia actually has a list of commercial flights: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airline_flights_that_required_gliding